# Access a function within an array of functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

create a variable where is a function and within that function there is a set of array of functions, I want to access the third level but I can not, send me an error, someone has an idea that I am doing wrong?

```js
var mivarobject = function(){

  // array functions
  helpers = {

    // functions
    function1 : function(){
      return 1;
    },
    function2 : function(){
      return 2;
    },

  }

}


console.log(mivarobject.helpers.function1());
```

With this I get the following error: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'function1' of undefined**

Comment: @MarkMeyer edited

Comment: @TylerRoper ´´miravobject is not defined´´

Comment: there are no arrays in the code you posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `new` keyword, assuming your intention is to use `mivarobject` as a class.

Additionally, you're declaring `helpers` globally. Add `this` to instantiate it as a property of `mivarobject`.

```js
var mivarobject = function(){
  this.helpers = {
    function1: function(){
      return 1;
    }
  };
};

console.log((new mivarobject).helpers.function1());
```

Comment: This was the most reliable solution, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

`mivarobject` is an function so you can return value from it and than you need to access `function1` on returned value

```js
var mivarobject = function(){
  let helpers = {
    function1 : function(){
      return 1;
    }
  }
  return helpers
}

console.log(mivarobject().function1());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `helpers` and call `mivarobject`:

```js
var mivarobject = function() {
  var helpers = {
    function1: function() {
      return 1;
    },
    function2: function() {
      return 2;
    }
  };
  return helpers;
};

console.log(mivarobject().function1());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `mivarobject` just is a function what returns `void` - nothing, then `mivarobject.helpers` is `undefined`, because a function in Js does not has `helpers` property.

We have `some` ways to get your point, use `mivarobject` as a normal function, the function return `helpers` object (not array), when you want to use `function1` you have to `call` `mivarobject` function, ex: `console.log(mivarobject.helpers.function1());`

Use `immediate function` is my way, create a function and call it immediately, `mivarobject` will be come a object.

```
var mivarobject = (function() {
    // array functions
    helpers = {

        // functions
        function1: function() {
            return 1;
        },
        function2: function() {
            return 2;
        },

    }

    return helpers;
})();


console.log(mivarobject.helpers.function1());
```