# Access an internal function within an array of functions

Tags: javascript, function, object

I have the following code, it is a variable that has an array of functions, but I can not access them, send an error. What I need between them is help but send me an error when trying to access one of them within the other.

```
var mivarobject = function(){
  this.helpers = {
    function1: function(){
      return 1;
    },
    function2: function(){
      return this.helpers.function1() + 1;
    },
  };
};

console.log((new mivarobject()).helpers.function2());
```

How can I access between them?

Comment: you already asked ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55555219/access-a-function-within-an-array-of-functions - oh, wait ... you've got the answer from there, and now trying to do something else, sorry - you need to learn how `this` works

Comment: not, this is another very different question, I need to call a function inside another internal

Comment: it's not very different, it's a continuation of the previous one :p but ... `function2: function(){
      return this.helpers.function1() + 1;
    }.bind(this)` or `function2: () => {
      return this.helpers.function1() + 1;
    }` will suffice

Comment: @JaromandaX oh my god!, `.bind(this)`? , why ?

Comment: because javascript

Comment: @JaromandaX It is difficult for me to understand what you have just done, it is my solution, but I still do not understand why in that way.

Comment: it works because [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) does what you want

Comment: It there a reason you are doing it this way rather than just putting the methods on the `mivarobject` prototype like a normal class? Seems like you are making more work for yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me, they are very kind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use `bind` or an arrow function:

```js
var mivarobject = function() {
  this.helpers = {
    function1: function() {
      return 1;
    },
    function2: function() {
      return this.helpers.function1() + 1;
    }.bind(this),
  };
};

console.log((new mivarobject()).helpers.function2());
```

---

```js
var mivarobject = function() {
  this.helpers = {
    function1: function() {
      return 1;
    },
    function2: () => this.helpers.function1() + 1,
  };
};

console.log((new mivarobject()).helpers.function2());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you call `function2` as a method of `helpers`, its `this` value is set to `helpers`. If `function2` wants to call another method of `helpers`, it can be reached as a property of `this`. Basically, the reference to `this.helpers` is both superfluous and incorrect.

Change the function2 definition to

```
function2: function(){
  return this.function1() + 1;
}
```

and it will work as expected.

Comment: This solution is much more attractive and understandable to me, 
Although I have several sets of functions within arrays, such as 'helpers', 'funcs', 'actions' then the functions are called internally between them. The solution of **Jaromanda X** and **Jack Bashford** satisfies this.

thank you very much.